# Mysql Error - Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

do you find any issue in these below MySQL query. Actually this Insert query is not working. the tools picks the values from FORM controls correctly but it is not updating.

the values ain't update in MySQL DB. the coding brings the form values correctly but it is not updating in MySQL DB
actually the query where i am using in VB.Net (VS2010)

```
  Private Sub btnupdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click
    Dim ch_date As Date = dtpdate.Value

    If ch_date = getToday(Now) Then
        checkdate(ch_date)
    Else
        checkdate(ch_date)
    End If

    cleanfields()
End Sub


Function checkdate(ByVal chdate As Date)
    Dim tmpreader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim usr As String
    'Dim dtp_date As Date = dtpdate.Value
    usr = getUserName()
    usr = getFullName(getUserName())

    Try
        If main_form.mySQLconn1.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            main_form.mySQLconn1.Open()
        End If

        main_form.cmdproductivity.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM productivity WHERE productivity_date = @productivity_date"
        main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@productivity_date").Value = chdate
        tmpreader = main_form.cmdproductivity.ExecuteReader()

        If tmpreader.HasRows Then

            main_form.cmdproductivity.CommandText = "UPDATE productivity SET agent = @agent, productivity_date = @productivity_date, actual_date = @actual_date, total_count = @total_count, eq_pr = @eq_pr, c_rebook=@c_rebook, c_nonwatson=@c_nonwatson, c_coa=@c_coa, c_watson=@c_watson, c_velocity=@c_velocity, c_quote=@c_quote, c_crd=@c_crd, c_eclaims=@c_eclaims, c_ecalls=@c_ecalls, c_xi=@c_xi, c_brazil=@c_brazil, c_cancel=@c_cancel, c_queries=@c_queries, c_partrebook=@c_partrebook, c_nci=@c_nci, c_phil=@c_phil, c_qc=@c_qc, c_watsonqc=@c_watsonqc, c_monitor=@c_monitor, c_enduser=@c_enduser, c_idoc=@c_idoc, c_servercancel=@c_servercancel, eq_rebook=@eq_rebook, eq_nonwatson=@eq_nonwatson, eq_coa=@eq_coa, eq_watson=@eq_watson, eq_velocity=@eq_velocity, eq_quote=@eq_quote, eq_crd=@eq_crd, eq_eclaims=@eq_eclaims, eq_ecalls=@eq_ecalls, eq_xi=@eq_xi, eq_brazil=@eq_brazil, eq_cancel=@eq_cancel, eq_queries=@eq_queries, eq_partrebook=@eq_partrebook, eq_nci=@eq_nci, eq_phil=@eq_phil, eq_qc=@eq_qc, eq_watsonqc=@eq_watsonqc, eq_monitor=@eq_monitor, eq_enduser=@eq_enduser, eq_idoc=@eq_idoc, eq_servercancel=@eq_servercancel WHERE productivity_date = @productivity_date"

            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@agent").Value = Trim(usr)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@productivity_date").Value = Trim(chdate)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@actual_date").Value = getToday(Now)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@total_count").Value = Trim(txtcount.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_pr").Value = Trim(txtEQPRs.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_rebook").Value = Trim(txtrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_nonwatson").Value = Trim(txtnonwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_coa").Value = Trim(txtcoa.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_watson").Value = Trim(txtwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_velocity").Value = Trim(txtvelocity.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_quote").Value = Trim(txtquote.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_crd").Value = Trim(txtcrd.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_eclaims").Value = Trim(txteclaims.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_ecalls").Value = Trim(txtecalls.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_xi").Value = Trim(txtxi.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_brazil").Value = Trim(txtbrazil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_cancel").Value = Trim(txtcancel.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_queries").Value = Trim(txtqueries.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_partrebook").Value = Trim(txtpartrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_nci").Value = Trim(txtnci.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_phil").Value = Trim(txtphil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_qc").Value = Trim(txtqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_watsonqc").Value = Trim(txtwatsonqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_monitor").Value = Trim(txtmonitor.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_enduser").Value = Trim(txtenduser.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_idoc").Value = Trim(txtidoc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_servercancel").Value = Trim(txtservercancel.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_rebook").Value = Trim(txtEQrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_nonwatson").Value = Trim(txtEQnonwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_coa").Value = Trim(txtEQcoa.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_watson").Value = Trim(txtEQwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_velocity").Value = Trim(txtEQvelocity.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_quote").Value = Trim(txtEQquote.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_crd").Value = Trim(txtEQcrd.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_eclaims").Value = Trim(txtEQeclaims.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_ecalls").Value = Trim(txtEQecalls.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_xi").Value = Trim(txtEQxi.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_brazil").Value = Trim(txtEQbrazil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_cancel").Value = Trim(txtEQcancel.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_queries").Value = Trim(txtEQqueries.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_partrebook").Value = Trim(txtEQpartrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_nci").Value = Trim(txtEQnci.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_phil").Value = Trim(txtEQphil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_qc").Value = Trim(txtEQqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_watsonqc").Value = Trim(txtEQwatsonqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_monitor").Value = Trim(txtEQmonitor.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_enduser").Value = Trim(txtEQenduser.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_idoc").Value = Trim(txtEQidoc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_servercancel").Value = Trim(txtEQservercancel.Text)

        Else

            'main_form.cmdproductivity.CommandText = "INSERT INTO productivity " _
            '                                       & "(agent,productivity_date,actual_date,total_count,eq_pr,c_rebook,c_nonwatson,c_coa,c_watson,c_velocity,c_quote,c_crd,c_eclaims,c_ecalls,c_xi,c_brazil,c_cancel,c_queries,c_partrebook,c_nci,c_phil,c_qc,c_watsonqc,c_monitor,c_enduser,c_idoc,c_servercancel,eq_rebook,eq_nonwatson,eq_coa,eq_watson,eq_velocity,eq_quote,eq_crd,eq_eclaims,eq_ecallseq_xi,eq_brazil,eq_cancel,eq_queries,eq_partrebook,eq_nci,eq_phil,eq_qc,eq_watsonqc,eq_monitor,eq_enduser,eq_idoc,eq_servercancel VALUES" _
            '                                       & "(@agent,@productivity_date,@actual_date,@total_count,@eq_pr,@c_rebook,@c_nonwatson,@c_coa,@c_watson,@c_velocity,@c_quote,@c_crd,@c_eclaims,@c_ecalls,@c_xi,@c_brazil,@c_cancel,@c_queries,@c_partrebook,@c_nci,@c_phil,@c_qc,@c_watsonqc,@c_monitor,@c_enduser,@c_idoc,@c_servercancel,@eq_rebook,@eq_nonwatson,@eq_coa,@eq_watson,@eq_velocity,@eq_quote,@eq_crd,@eq_eclaims,@eq_ecalls,@eq_xi,@eq_brazil,@eq_cancel,@eq_queries,@eq_partrebook,@eq_nci,@eq_phil,@eq_qc,@eq_watsonqc,@eq_monitor,@eq_enduser,@eq_idoc,@eq_servercancel)"


            main_form.cmdproductivity.CommandText = "INSERT INTO productivity(agent, productivity_date, actual_date, total_count, eq_pr, c_rebook, c_nonwatson, c_coa, c_watson, c_velocity, c_quote, c_crd, c_eclaims, c_ecalls, c_xi, c_brazil, c_cancel, c_queries, c_partrebook, c_nci, c_phil, c_qc, c_watsonqc, c_monitor, c_enduser, c_idoc, c_servercancel, eq_rebook, eq_nonwatson, eq_coa, eq_watson, eq_velocity, eq_quote, eq_crd, eq_eclaims, eq_ecalls, eq_xi, eq_brazil, eq_cancel, eq_queries, eq_partrebook, eq_nci, eq_phil, eq_qc, eq_watsonqc, eq_monitor, eq_enduser, eq_idoc, eq_servercancel) VALUES (@agent,@productivity_date,@actual_date,@total_count,@eq_pr,@c_rebook,@c_nonwatson,@c_coa,@c_watson,@c_velocity,@c_quote,@c_crd,@c_eclaims,@c_ecalls,@c_xi,@c_brazil,@c_cancel,@c_queries,@c_partrebook,@c_nci,@c_phil,@c_qc,@c_watsonqc,@c_monitor,@c_enduser,@c_idoc,@c_servercancel,@eq_rebook,@eq_nonwatson,@eq_coa,@eq_watson,@eq_velocity,@eq_quote,@eq_crd,@eq_eclaims,@eq_ecalls,@eq_xi,@eq_brazil,@eq_cancel,@eq_queries,@eq_partrebook,@eq_nci,@eq_phil,@eq_qc,@eq_watsonqc,@eq_monitor,@eq_enduser,@eq_idoc,@eq_servercancel)"
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@agent").Value = Trim(usr)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@productivity_date").Value = Trim(chdate)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@actual_date").Value = getToday(Now)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@total_count").Value = Trim(txtcount.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_pr").Value = Trim(txtEQPRs.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_rebook").Value = Trim(txtrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_nonwatson").Value = Trim(txtnonwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_coa").Value = Trim(txtcoa.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_watson").Value = Trim(txtwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_velocity").Value = Trim(txtvelocity.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_quote").Value = Trim(txtquote.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_crd").Value = Trim(txtcrd.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_eclaims").Value = Trim(txteclaims.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_ecalls").Value = Trim(txtecalls.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_xi").Value = Trim(txtxi.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_brazil").Value = Trim(txtbrazil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_cancel").Value = Trim(txtcancel.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_queries").Value = Trim(txtqueries.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_partrebook").Value = Trim(txtpartrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_nci").Value = Trim(txtnci.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_phil").Value = Trim(txtphil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_qc").Value = Trim(txtqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_watsonqc").Value = Trim(txtwatsonqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_monitor").Value = Trim(txtmonitor.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_enduser").Value = Trim(txtenduser.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_idoc").Value = Trim(txtidoc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@c_servercancel").Value = Trim(txtservercancel.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_rebook").Value = Trim(txtEQrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_nonwatson").Value = Trim(txtEQnonwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_coa").Value = Trim(txtEQcoa.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_watson").Value = Trim(txtEQwatson.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_velocity").Value = Trim(txtEQvelocity.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_quote").Value = Trim(txtEQquote.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_crd").Value = Trim(txtEQcrd.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_eclaims").Value = Trim(txtEQeclaims.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_ecalls").Value = Trim(txtEQecalls.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_xi").Value = Trim(txtEQxi.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_brazil").Value = Trim(txtEQbrazil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_cancel").Value = Trim(txtEQcancel.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_queries").Value = Trim(txtEQqueries.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_partrebook").Value = Trim(txtEQpartrebook.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_nci").Value = Trim(txtEQnci.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_phil").Value = Trim(txtEQphil.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_qc").Value = Trim(txtEQqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_watsonqc").Value = Trim(txtEQwatsonqc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_monitor").Value = Trim(txtEQmonitor.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_enduser").Value = Trim(txtEQenduser.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_idoc").Value = Trim(txtEQidoc.Text)
            main_form.cmdproductivity.Parameters("@eq_servercancel").Value = Trim(txtEQservercancel.Text)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Database Error: " & ex.ToString() & vbCrLf & "The error have been logged .... ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, main_form.dbErrTitle)
        writeLogs("Database Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        main_form.mySQLconn1.Close()
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: What is the issue which you are facing as it is really difficult to understand from your query what is the problem which you are facing?

Comment: Please, add you full error message.

Comment: I'm going to assume (due to lack of information) - that it has something to do with missing single quotes around strings, unless you do that elsewhere before assigning the variables.

Comment: are you using pdo or mysqli or mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't calculate your column number, but do you miss one column at end? where is the last id which exists in column but not in  VALUSE part:
(eq_servercancel, id) vs
(@eq_servercancel)

Comment: I have added the edited version please look into that and provide me the solution, only the INSERT query is not working and the values aren't reflecting in MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you edit your answer with the error you are getting, but at a glance:

You are adding "id" to you column list in the INSERT statement, but you do not have a "id" value in your VALUES statement.  So either remove "id" from the INSERT statement or send through a value for "id".

Comment: I have added the edited version please look into that and provide me the solution, only the INSERT query is not working and the values aren't reflecting in MySQL DB.

Comment: In your first INSERT query, at the end of the field list, before VALUES, you are missing a closing bracket - ")".